# What is the first North Korean song in this video called?

Tags: identify-this-song, korean

I really like the first song played. However, it's mixed together with the street noises in the video, so my downloaded copy of that video, minus the video, is full of noise. I'd like a "clean" version of the song only, without the sounds mixed in from the video recording.

For this reason, I'm trying to figure out what the title of the song is, or, specifically that recording of it. Even better yet, maybe you can link me directly to such a YouTube video where that song plays "cleanly"?

Comment: Maybe Shazam is lost but Google search on my phone has no problem identifying this song, despite the ambient noise.

Answer (score 1):

The song is Unification Rainbow (통일무지개), as performed by Pochonbo Electronic Ensemble (보천보전자악단).